# Did the stereotypical horniness of bards come up some time after development or where they part of the original fantasy/intended design?

Tags: bard, history-of-gaming

This question came up yesterday.

One argument I found in the internet was paladins being lawful good and bard being the only other charisma focused class at the time.
This could mean and emergent property based on the situation.
The other was the already existing stereotype of the "Drugs and Sex and Rock and Roll" musician.

Are there any actual sources for this?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov to me that looks like it helps but begs the question "If not in the original concept, then where from?"

Comment: The artist Fredrik K.T. Andersson was an influence on the "horny bard" trend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### It's a joke that originated online rather than in D&D canon.

During the era when TSR published AD&D (1977 to 1997), there was an internal policy to avoid potentially offensive content, including sexual content or works depicting explicitly Judeo-Christian religious elements. After Gary Gygax left the company in the mid-1980s, they even banned the names "demon" and "devil" for fear of offending religious parents. TSR's James M. Ward even had an official policy for this, called the Angry Mothers rule.

AD&D's bards weren't entirely sexless. It would have been generally understood that bards, as performers, would need to be good-looking and charming, more so than any other character class. *The Complete Bard's Handbook* (1992) even had a kit called the Gallant, a romantic warrior whose hobbies including romancing the opposite sex.

In D&D 3rd edition (2000), the d20 System allowed characters of any class to roll Charisma checks, including checks to influence NPCs. The bard in particular became the "party face", i.e. the guy who initiates all conversations with NPCs because they have the highest number. Sorcerers also had high Charisma, but didn't have the Diplomacy skill, and paladins had to split their stats among other ability scores so they didn't always have the best Charisma. Bards also had more spells and abilities for charm purposes. The bard thus became the iconic character for influencing people, including those of the opposite sex.

It's not really until everyone got online that the "horny bard" trope arose. TV Tropes' page on the matter mainly cites post-2000 sources and web content, which seems to support this.

The origin of the "horny bard" appears to  be the D&D parody movie *The Gamers: Dorkness Rising* (2008), which has this exchange:

> Leo: I seduce the priestess!
>
> Lodge: She's taken a vow of celibacy!
>
> Leo: Dude, 20 ranks in seduction!
>
> Flynn the Fine: [to priestess] Hey, baby. Wanna tune my mandolin?
>
> [rolls and the priestess and Flynn leave the room]
>
> Daphne: [to Hierophant]  Please understand the horny bard does not represent us.

This in turn probably reflects the [Dead Alewives sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5t-y_ENDlo) (1996 or so) which has this exchange involving a player character (not a bard) in a tavern:

> Player: Ogres? Man, I got an ogre slaying knife, it's got a +9 against ogres!
>
> DM: You're not there, you're getting drunk!
>
> Player: Alright, but if there's any girls there, I wanna *do* them!

*Dorkness Rising* certainly helped the popularize the term, though it isn't the earliest known use of the phrase "horny bard". For example, in [this thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2gizr?Your-weirdest-character-names-ever#38), dated December 2005:

> In one Diskworld-esque game that never got entierly off the ground, I had a horny bard named Randy.

The "horny bard" trope has seen a surge of popularity post-2020. The earliest YouTube results for the term are May 2021, except for one obscure Witcher 3 video dated June 2016. A video game soundtrack by a band named Horny Bard appears on Steam dated June 2021. I suspect that the trope has been popularized recently by appearances at Reddit's /r/dndmemes. It may also have a connection to a related trope where dragons are promiscuous, which comes from D&D 3.5's popular half-dragon template and the notion that sorcerers are often descended from dragons.

Comment: Re: "It's not really until everyone got online that the "horny bard" trope arose."  Rule 34?

Comment: It's worth looing at the original description of the bard for 1e AD&D, and the predecessor document reprinted in Best Of Dragon, Vol 1, by Doug Schwengman.  Those treat the bard fairly seriously, as part of a fantasized Celtic pastiche, not as horny medieval rock stars.  The closest you'd find is in Schwengman's original take, a lengthy discussion on the (mechanically antiquated) Charm spell, which **could** support sexual antics... but doesn't actually do so on the page.

Comment: [Low IRL Cha meet high in game Cha](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/jjcoxv/where_did_the_stereotype_of_the_horny_bard_come/?rdt=50316)

Answer (score -3):

Pre-internet it's tough to say what most people thought, but Dragon Magazine ran comic strips featuring a useless greedy thief (Fineous Fingers) and a "lawful stupid" paladin, but I can't recall any bards. Next, in 1990 the comic-book D&D parody "Knights of the Dinner Table" started. It was full of rules lawyer jokes, mages being too difficult for beginners, killer DM's, but I can't recall much about bards there either.

The first big mention might be the popular 2004 PlayStation-2 game "The Bard's Tale". It had the main character as a total scumbag named "The Bard" who only wanted sex and beer-money. The first mission has the typical tavern with a well-endowed barmaid who needs rats killed. But after doing that and choosing the "be rude to her" option -- she takes you up to her room for the night. One of the endings lets you decide the Demon Queen is a total babe and you free her. The narration was pretty good and constantly describes the character as a selfish jerk.